# How to use Youtube Player API with jQuery in in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

I'm using Magento 2.4 and i'm trying to use Youtube player API with jQuery in Magento 2 .phtml file like this first:

```
<script>
    require(['jquery'], function($){
        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

However it is not working at all, then I tried to inject the youtube player api script in **requirejs-config.js** like this:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*':{
            youTubeIFrame: 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api?noext'
        }
    }
};
```

.phtml file:

```
<script>
    require(['jquery','youTubeIFrame'], function($,YT){...
```

but the youtube video does not appear at all

Is there a correct way to load the Youtube Player API with jQuery in MAgento 2 ?